# JPA: How to search by multiple properties using spring-data

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to fetch the data from user and contact tables based on multiple parameters which are passed from UI e.g. username, userType, emailId, phoneNumber etc combined together.

The User Entity class looks like this:
`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User
{
    private String usertId;
    private Collection<Contact> contacts;
    private String userType;
    private username;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
    public Collection<Contact> getContacts()
    {
        return contacts;
    }

    //getters & setters
}
```

`And its child class`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact
{
    private  String phoneNumber;
    private  String zipCode;
    private  String emailId;
    private  String addressText;


    //getters & setters
}
```

`And the UserRepository class is:`

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByContacts_ZipCode(String zipCode); //Individual parameter search is working perfectly fine
}
```

`
How to create search criteria in JPA for multiple fields which are from either parent or child objects fields and any one/some or all of them could be passed from UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by extending 
JpaSpecificationExecutor in your repository and create specifications for it.
[Please refer this](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)